# How to install HAXM shows system couldn't find the environment option that was entered

Tags: android-studio, installation, environment-variables, haxm

I have tried installing haxm in android studio several times, but everytime it shows up an error message that "System couldn't find the environment option that was entered". Hyper V is already disabled. How to rectify the environment problem?

Answer (score 0):

Download and Install HAXM Setup File from the below URL and check

https://github.com/intel/haxm/releases